# dns_get_records behave differently

Tags: php, docker, php-7.2, dns-get-record

I have a php script which runs inside a docker (The **php version is 7.2.34 on orcalelinux**. ) it uses dns_get_records to fetch spf records for domains. For one particular domain it throws a warning:

```
Warning dns_get_record(): a temporary server error has occurred on line 7
```

and returns  blank result.

I tried to run same script on **php:7.2-fpm-alpine** the result is same but a different warning:

```
Warning: dns_get_record(): Unable to parse DNS data received on line 7
```

But When I run the script on my wsl linux (**Ubuntu with php version 7.2.34**) the script executes without warning and returns valid result for same domain

Why is same php function behaving differently on three different environment, and how it can be fixed?

**My host operating system is windows 11**
Here is php script:

```
<?php

/* do some stuff*/



$spf = dns_get_record('somedomain',DNS_TXT);
print("---------------------------------SMC SPF record---------------------------------\n");
print("\n$spf\n");
print("---------------------------------SMC SPF record---------------------------------\n");
?>
```

I cannot expose domain name due to privacy issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research I found that docker from windows is messing up the name servers in the container so the domain name was not able to get resolved properly hence the temporary error. so I had to edit **/etc/resolve.conf** in my container to

```
1.1.1.1
```

and it started working properly.
I still face issues with curl based APIs in the container so I have decided to run docker inside wsl2 instead.